# MVC 4 Unable to call javascript function from another js file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying call the loadTimesheet function in object weeklytimesheet from another js file.

I get a Object doesn't support property or method 'loadTimesheet' error.

EDIT: My intellisense in VS2012 is not working either if that has any bearing on it.

mylester.index.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#newtimesheet").click(function () {
        weeklytimesheet.loadTimesheet();
    });
});
```

mylester.weeklytimesheet.js

```
var weeklytimesheet = new function () {
    load = function () {
        var wkending =  getWeekEnding();
        var proId = $("#newtimesheet").attr("proid");
        $("#divtimesheet").load("/Timesheet/NewTimesheet", new { proId: proID, enddate: wkending });
        open();
    };

    open = function() {
        $("#clipboarddialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            height: 800,
            width: 860,
            modal: true,
            title: "Edit Timesheet",
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    editorForm.saveForm();
                    $(this).dialog("close")
                },
                Cancel: function () { $(this).dialog("close") }
            }
        });

    };

    getWeekEnding = function () {
        var wkending;
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        $("#datepickerdialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            close: function () {
                wkending = $("#weekending").val();
            },
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });
        return wkending;
    }

    return
    {
        loadTimesheet: load
    };
}();
```

Comment: And I suppose the files are included in the right order? Is the file being loaded correctly (check your dev tools)

Comment: Because the second piece of javascript is assigning to a variable, the variable must be in scope (declared and set) prior to where your first piece of javascript is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that carriage return after the `new`, it tells the function to return `undefined`. fix it this way:

```
return {
  loadTimesheet: load
};
```

This machanism is known as semicolon insertion is one of the 'awful parts' of JavaScript that Douglas Crockford lists in his excellent book, [JavaScript, The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do).

Also, I suggest 2 improvements in your code :

1) don't use `new`. It's not meant for what you are doing here. If what you want is a local scope for declaring your helper functions, here's a trick : use a function expression that you that you call immediately:

```
  var weeklytimesheet = (function () {
    // do your local stuff ...
    return {
      loadTimesheet: load
    };
  } ()); // see? call the function immediately. That's how you make nontrivial expressions in JS.
```

2) Don't assign variables that you have not declared (`load`, `open`, `getWeekEnding`). You may have got this habit from Python, but in JavaScript it has a very bad effect : these variables are interpreted as properties of the global Object (`window`), which makes them not local at all and pollutes the global namespace. I think you don't want that; using function declarations (`function open () {...}`) solves this neatly.

So to sum up, here is how I would rewrite your code :

```
var weeklytimesheet = (function () {
  function load () {
    var wkending =  getWeekEnding();
    var proId = $("#newtimesheet").attr("proid");
    $("#divtimesheet").load("/Timesheet/NewTimesheet", new { proId: proID, enddate: wkending });
    open();
  }

  function open () {
    $("#clipboarddialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      height: 800,
      width: 860,
      modal: true,
      title: "Edit Timesheet",
      buttons: {
        "Save": function () {
          editorForm.saveForm();
          $(this).dialog("close")
        },
        Cancel: function () { $(this).dialog("close") }
      }
    });

  }

  function getWeekEnding () {
    var wkending;
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#datepickerdialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      close: function () {
        wkending = $("#weekending").val();
      },
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });
    return wkending;
  }

  return {
    loadTimesheet: load
  };

}());
```

Comment: One other thing. I have jquery ui in the _references.js file. But the $("#divtimesheet").load this is giving same error as the other one. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery UI, but I see another problem in that line : `new { proId: proID, enddate: wkending }`. It makes no sense to use `new` with an object. And again, don't use `new` unless a library forces you to.